# Two skew lines on a smooth projective surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth complex projective surface. Let $L_1,L_2$ be two skew lines on $X$ i.e $L_1.L_2=0$. Then can we conclude that $h^0(\mathcal O_{L_1}(-L_2))=0$?

From what I know this only happens if the product intersection number is negative. Is there a special reason for this to happen in this particular situation?

Any insight from anyone on whether this is right or wrong is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the assumption $L_1 \cdot L_2 = 0$ implies
$$
\mathcal{O}_X(-L_2)\vert_{L_1} \cong \mathcal{O}_{L_1},
$$
hence it has a non-zero global section.